# Blazor WASM Site on IIS stopped working after just a few days with integrity checking error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I had deployed a Blazor Web Assembly with API site (based on the repo here: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/ModernWebDevWithBlazorWasm) to a Windows Server 2016 running IIS. I published the files locally from Visual Studio and then copied them to the server.

I had an issue with some resources at first, as I had created a subsite under the Default Website to test it out. Ultimately, it seemed that removing the leading "" from the images seemed to allow it to resolve the "base" url that I needed to add into the index.html.

So it was all working fine on the Friday. Then yesterday, had a look at the site, and it's just not loading, giving me these errors:

[image: Blazor WASM Integrity Error]

It appears that there is some Integrity checking on certain files that is failing. After googling, I could see that it's documented issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0

But unfortunately, no cleaning, deleting caches/build artifacts, rebuilding, redeploying seems to be working for me. I've tried multiple browsers, and all suffer an error although in FireFox it was slightly different. I've seen some similar people commenting about being able to resolve it or just left unanswered, so I'm quite puzzled what is going on.

I'm very keen on implementing Blazor for this project, but now I'm quite concerned as it's an absolute Show Stopper for me...I'm hoping it's something stupid that I've done, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I've just had a thought, I installed .NET 6 Hosting Bundle on the server, but never restarted it. Could it have been a Windows Update and restart that has caused this to happen? Because I hadn't actually touched the machine in that period over the weekend.

I've just deployed to another server and it's working fine at the moment, but again, haven't restarted IIS or the machine after installing the .NET 6 Hosting Bundle...?

Comment: Are you modifying the contents of any files after publishing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not actually touch the files, I just went to the website and then noticed it was failing. I am doing a Blue/Green deployment on this server, so I tried re-building/publishing to the alternate folder, but that won't work either.